# Problem connecting to postgresql from external windows machine

Tags: postgresql, windows

I have a Windows laptop running a postgresql database. I want to be able to pull data from this DB into an application on another laptop, say excel or access.

So far, I set up a DSN on my machine and it works fine if I want to pull data into excel on my machine. However, I cannot successfully replicate this process on another machine. I have already installed the Postgres ODBC driver on this machine.

Can anybody help me through this process? I'm completely new to database administration and mostly do not know what I am doing - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should do a `telnet` to your Windows laptop to figure out exact issue. The issue may be firewall, `pg_hba.conf`, wrong configurations and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit *pg_hba.conf* file in your Postgres installation, and add an entry to allow access via other machine or allow network range.

```
host    all             all             10.10.10.0/24           trust
```

As you had success accessing Postgres on the same machine, that could be the reason.
Access via localhost is default.
Let us know if worked.

Comment: Thank you, I made the change to the pg_hba.conf file and it seems to be working!